# Easiest way to import excel dataset into preexisting SQL table?

Tags: sql, excel, import

I have a table that has FY17-FY19 data, I want to append FY20 data. What would be the easiest way to accurately do this? I don't want to have to recreate a new table.

Answer (score 1):

So, you can save Excel file to. csv (File-Save As)
Then you write :

```
BULK INSERT TableName-- your table
FROM 'C:\FileName.csv'    --Your path to file 
WITH
(

FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' --Use to shift the control to next row

)
```

Comment: Does this have options associated with quoted strings?

Comment: SQL Server interprets the quoted comma as a delimiter. This applies to both BCP and bulk insert .

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485%28v=sql.100%29.aspx